# Java print only specific section in a swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to print a certain section in my Java GUI swing. So basically I have a frame and then other views like textfield, label, table and then panel. Inside the panel I have two buttons. I want to exclude in printing the panel that contains two buttons. How can I do that? So far this is the code I've done:

```
  setTitle("VMS Sales Invoice");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 397, 628);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

  JLabel lblVatable = new JLabel("VATable");
    lblVatable.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 12));
    lblVatable.setBounds(158, 468, 55, 16);
    getContentPane().add(lblVatable);

    txtTotalDiscount = new JTextField();
    txtTotalDiscount.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 12));
    txtTotalDiscount.setEditable(false);
    txtTotalDiscount.setBounds(256, 485, 122, 28);
    getContentPane().add(txtTotalDiscount);
    txtTotalDiscount.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblTotalDiscount = new JLabel("Total Discount");
    lblTotalDiscount.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 12));
    lblTotalDiscount.setBounds(158, 496, 86, 16);
    getContentPane().add(lblTotalDiscount);

  setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); // THIS WILL CENTRE THE POSITION OF WINDOW
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


  public class btnPrintAction implements ActionListener, Printable{
    public int print(Graphics gx, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException {

        if (page > 0){
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        } // Only one page
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gx; // Cast to Graphics2D object
        g.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY()); // Match origins to imageable area
        //g.drawString ("Hello world", 100, 100); // Print Hello World at offset (100, 100)

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        // Print the entire visible contents of a
        // java.awt.Frame.
        getContentPane().printAll(g);


        return PAGE_EXISTS; // Page exists (offsets start at zero!)

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob(); // Get the printer's job list
        job.setPrintable(this); // We print with this class (btnPrintAction, which implements Printable)
        if (job.printDialog() == true) { // If we clicked OK in the print dialog
            try {
                job.print();
            } catch (PrinterException ex){
                // It did not work (PrinterException thrown), so add any error handling routines.
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString(), "Printing Error",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas how to achieve this? I need to get this working. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Split your UI into different sections (across multiple components), up those components you want to print and those you don't, then simply print the panel you do want printed...

Answer (score 2):

Define clip region for the Graphics used for print.

```
g.setClip(int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

Where parameters for clip is the panel bounds.

Comment: There's also a [setClip that takes a Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setClip%28java.awt.Shape%29) if excluding the buttons would be non-rectangular.

Comment: @Stanislavl can you give me some sample implementation of this?

Answer (score 2):

Some solutions I can think of:

- Put the buttons in a different panel (easy, recommended).
- Set the buttons invisible with setVisible(false) during the print and visible again after (keeping in mind setVisible does more than meets the eye).
- Tinker with the print mechanism manually with overrides for print/printAll/printChildren (not recommended).